# Redux - Global concept - Display message depends on boolean

Tags: reactjs, redux, connect

I have an issue with Redux and I can't find where is going wrong. My idea : I want to display a message depends on if the user already exists on my database. I used redux-react but it's really confusing for me.
1 - my action

```
import { SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT} from "./types";

export const msgRegisterSuccess = () => {
    return {
       type: SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT
    };
 };
```

2 - My reducer

```
import {SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT} from "../actions/types";

export default function (state=false,action){
   switch(action.type){
      case SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT:
         return !state.submitToggle;

      default:
         return state;
   }
};
```

3 - My container

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { registerUser } from "../../actions/registerActions";

import Validate from "../../components/form/Validate";
import Contact from "../../components/auth/Contact";

const ContactPage = ({ registerUser}) => {
   const [user, setUser] = useState({
      user_name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
      errors: {}
   });

   const handleChange = e => {
      setUser({
         ...user,
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      });
   };

   const handleBlur = e => {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      const err = { ...user.errors, ...Validate(name, value).errors };
      setUser({ ...user, errors: { ...err } });
   };

   const handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { user_name, email, message} = user;
      registerUser({ user_name, email, message});
   };

   return (

      <div>
         <Contact
            user={{ ...user}}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
         />

      </div>

   );
};

ContactPage.propTypes = {
   registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   toggle: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   errors: state.errors,
   toggle: state.toggle
});

export default connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   { registerUser }
)(ContactPage);
```

4 - where I would like to dispatch my "SET_SUBMIT_MESSAGE" action if user data is saved in my data base. I know this particular snippet of code is wrong :(. I've try soooo many combinaison, I'm tired !!

```
import axios from "axios";
import {SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT} from "../actions/successMsgActions";


export const registerUser = (userData) => dispatch => {

   axios
      .post("/api/users/signup",userData)
      // .then(dispatch(SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT))
      .catch(err => {
         dispatch(setErrors(err.response.data));
         // dispatch(SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT);
      });
   };
```

Can someone please Help meee ?

Nad'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some inconsistency in state

Here it is boolean

`export default function (state=false,action){`

here you return state or boolean

```
   switch(action.type){
      case SET_MESSAGE_SUBMIT:
         return !state.submitToggle;

      default:
         return state;
   }
```

but in component you expect object

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   errors: state.errors,
   toggle: state.toggle
});
```

I didn't try all the code by myself, but other thinks seem to be ok.